'inq' authority errors for TARGET queues for multiple applications though ALIAS queue is granted with +allmqi
We are getting 'inq' authority errors for TARGET queues for multiple applications though ALIAS queue is granted with '+allmqi'. The timing of errors are random but for a few like 'kafka' we figured out that when kafka does MQ connectors restart sometimes those errors appear.
Does somebody faced similar issue? any suggestions ?
Based on the kafka timings I enabled tracing but error didn't appear when I enabled tracing. No luck

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Usually we grant authorities to the Alias queue, not to the base queue. The same has been done in our env. However, whenever applications restarts we get errors which says that application's id is trying to access 'inq' authority for the base queue.

This site explains that you also need inquire on the local queue, this is because the JMS API needs to inquire the back out queue details of the local queue.

Hi @JoshMc Agree, but For each MQI call using an alias, the queue manager resolves the real queue name, which could be either a local queue or a remote queue defined at this queue manager. So then '+allmqi' applies to TARGET queue and application must be able to inq any information from the queue. IBM also says that when we use alias queues , receiving application does not even know TARGET queue's name, so they must be inquiring those BOTHRESH &  BOQNAME from alias queue itself and then Qmgr's responsibility is to tell these values from TARGET queue. isn't it ?

Read the link I provided,  it works how it says from my observations.  Note that this is only for a consumer,  it would not apply to a QALIAS that targets a QREMOTE.  You can not inquire the BOTHRESH & BOQNAME on a QALIAS since those are not parameters of a QALIAS.

Thanks @JoshMc. would like to understand it more, so the JMS classes which is found on C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib on MQ server help to find the TARGET queue while handling the poison messages or the client end JMS classes do that.

Thanks @JoshMc. Just would like to understand it more clearly, so the JMS classes which is found on C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mqjms.jar on MQ server check the  "BackoutCount" from MQMD header and also find the TARGET queue while handling the poison messages do that. Correct ? . I also would like to tell here that  in our env. we never granted inq auth to TARGET queues and the backout queue setup still works fine for us. dont know how ?

Please read the link I provided, it is only in the specific case of a consumer that is pointed to a QALIAS which targets a QLOCAL.

Here is the quote that explains it "When inquiring the BOTHRESH and BOQNAME attributes, the IBM MQ classes for JMS:

Open the local queue, or the target queue for an alias queue.
Inquire the BOTHRESH and BOQNAME attributes.
Close the local queue, or the target queue for an alias queue."


There is also a specific case where it may need GET authority "... if the local queue, or the target queue for an alias queue, is a cluster queue, then the IBM MQ classes for JMS open the queue with the MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF, MQOO_INQUIRE and MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING options. This means that the user running the receiving application must have inquire and get access to the local instance of the cluster queue."

And this: "The IBM MQ classes for JMS open all other types of local queue with the open options MQOO_INQUIRE and MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING. In order for the IBM MQ classes for JMS to query the values of the attributes, the user running the receiving application must have inquire access on the local queue."
